# Transferring MSSQL Stored Procedures to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an MSSQL stored procedure as follows :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[user_CheckEMail]
            @Email          nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_Data WHERE EMail = @Email)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0
    END

END
```

In changing to MySQL I know that certain things need to change.  This is what I have :-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE server.`user_CheckEMail`(
                IN Email            nvarchar(200))
BEGIN

    DECLARE this_count int;
    SET this_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_Data WHERE EMail = Email)

    IF (this_count > 0) THEN
        RETURN 1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0
    END IF

END
```

In this state "int" is highlighted with "syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting ';'"

By removing the ";" the Declare line loses it's error, but the Set line now shows "syntax error, unexpected SET, expecting ';'"

If I remove the Declare statement altogether the Set line is fine and the If line returns "syntax error, unexpected IF, expecting ';'"

Finally, by placing ';' at the end of the Set statement the Set returns error "syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting ';'" while the If now errors "syntax error, unexpected IF"

I know that this is only a basic procedure, but I have about two dozen to move across and all are showing errors, so I'm hoping find out what I'm doing wrong here and I'll be able to cure all problems.....hopefully.

Comment: You need to surround the stored procedure with a `delimiter` statement :  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE server.`user_CheckEMail`(
                IN Email            nvarchar(200))
BEGIN



 DECLARE this_count int;
 SET this_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_Data WHERE EMail = Email);

 IF (this_count > 0) THEN
    RETURN 1
 ELSE
    RETURN 0
 END IF;

 END$$
```

By default MySQL treats semicolon(;) as the statement terminator or end of statement. But as we need to use it inside the procedure body, so we need another different delimiter to state the end of the stored procedure. Here `DELIMITER $$` sets `$$` as the statement terminator.

Comment: Brilliant, knew there had to be something silly.  Also, because it's a procedure, I had to add an OUT variable and set that rather than RETURN the value.